# ol.style.Rule is implemented in v3.0.0-beta.1 and not in v3.0.0

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openlayers

Can we use `ol.style.Rule` and `ol.expr.parse` in  OpenLayers-v3.0.0? I cannot find them but they are implemented in  OpenLayers-v3.0.0-beta.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/wLp0oWdVEmA/BBvfyDIoMlIJ) (at the very top of the page) that in OpenLayers 3, the functions you describe:

> "They have been removed and were "replaced” by style functions"

They also provide a link to [more information](http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/vector-style/style.html) regarding those functions and how they can be used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Most welcome, glad you got it working!